# Меняем местами отображение данных товара

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Допустим в woocommerce при детальном просмотре товара, нужно обернуть блоки рейтинг, краткое описание и цену в отдельный блок-обёртку и поменять местами цену и кр-е описание в этом новом блоке-обёртке.
Стандартная последовательность хуков такая:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_sharing', 50 );
```

Я удалил хуки нужных блоков так:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
```

добавляю новую функцию для обёрки так:
`add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_summary_after_title', 20 );
function woocommerce_summary_after_title() {
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 25 );
        echo '<hr />';
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 25 );
        echo '<hr />';
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 25 );
    echo '</div>';
}`
в результате на странице сначала идёт новый блок wrap, в котором две линии, потом уже под блоком wrap идут рейтинг, кр-е описание и цена.А нужно, чтобы рейтинг, кр-е описание и цена были в блоке wrap.
А если сделать так:
`function woocommerce_summary_after_title() {
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
        woocommerce_template_single_rating();
        echo '<hr />';
        woocommerce_template_single_excerpt();
        echo '<hr />';
        woocommerce_template_single_price();
    echo '</div>';
}`
то нужные блоки правильно расположены в новом блоке wrap.
Подскажите, как правильно нужно заключить блоки рейтинга, кр-е описание и цену в новый блок wrap ?
И почему 1й вариант функции woocommerce_summary_after_title() не работает, а 2й работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `add_action` не вызывает функцию, а добавляет ее в массив хуков. А вызов хуков из этого перечня осуществляется по `do_action` где-то в другом месте.

Первый вариант вашей функции внутри себя ничего не выводит, кроме wrap с двумя линиями. Потому и такой результат.

Comment: Ну а второй вариант вызова функции вообще правильный?
Там ведь вызов функций woocommerce_template_single_rating() идёт без хуков! т.е. хуки удалены с помощью remove_action

Comment: так если он работает - почему нет.

Comment: Вы напрямую вызываете функции WC из удобного места. Ну и на здоровье.